# Как запретить масштабирование 2gis при скролле?

Tags: javascript, карты, 2gis-api

Если вставить карту 2gis на сайт и делать скролл, то когда курсор дойдет до карты, то начинается масштабирование карты. И чтобы дальше скролить карту, то нужно пользоваться скролбаром(Карта почти на весь экран). Можно как-нибудь заблокировать масштабирование карты? Или сделать масштабирование карты только по клику мышки.

Answer (score 4):

Внимательнее изучайте [API 2gis](http://api.2gis.ru/doc/maps/ru/manual/map/#%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8), а именно раздел *Опции колеса мыши* и его параметр `scrollWheelZoom`. По умолчанию он в значении `true`.

Пример вызова со значением `scrollWheelZoom: false`:

```js
DG.then(function() {
  DG.map('map', {
    center: [54.98, 82.89],
    zoom: 13,
    dragging: false,
    touchZoom: false,
    scrollWheelZoom: false,
    doubleClickZoom: false,
    boxZoom: false,
    geoclicker: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.api.2gis.ru/2.0/loader.js"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>
```